# 3.6x Administrator - add class to squeezebox iframe on popup

Tags: administrator, template-override

My goal is to be able to change the content within [AddtoMenu](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/addtomenu) - so I can set the language by default rather than "all" - I want "en-gb" or "zh-TW" etc. based on my content type (am using FLEXIcontent).

AddtoMenu uses squeezebox to trigger iframe - and I can't work out how to edit the squeezebox iframe content. I can manipulate the #sbox-window its held in:

```
if ($("#jform_language").val() === "en-GB") {
$('#sbox-window').addClass('en');   
}
```

But how do I add a class to the iframe when it pops opens?

```
<a href="index.php?rl_qp=1&folder=administrator.modules.mod_addtomenu&file=popup.php&comp=item_old&vars[view]=item&vars[cid]=358&vars[option]=com_flexicontent&vars[task]=items.edit" class="btn btn-small addtomenu_link modal hasTooltip" title="<strong>Add to Menu</strong><br>Content item" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 600, y: 670}}"><span class="icon-reglab icon-addtomenu"></span> Add to Menu</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried to ask Peter at RegularLabs Forum https://www.regularlabs.com/forum/addtomenu ? Who is more knowledgeable about some extension than its developer...

Comment: Yes - the issue is now solved. Peter had added the feature to the latest experimental version:
https://www.regularlabs.com/development-releases

Comment: The you might consider posting that answer yourself and accept it. Otherwise question will stay in JSE system as unanswered for no reason.